# migrate millions of mysql data to different database with different structure in php script

Tags: php, mysql, multiprocess

I have 4 millions of data, which some column I need to migrate in a new MySQL database.
I need a PHP  script which I can run without any memory failure and any data.

I found it will be better to use multibatch process. Can anyone suggest what is the better option and how to do it in PHP and linux ?

Comment: Use mysql itself. Export and import. If the structure is different then you ve to write it yourself according the your situation, No template will do the custom job for you

Answer (score 1):

If the two databases are on the same server, then you could get good performance with a SELECT INTO, even across databases. Otherwise, you could export the data, and use load data in order to import it into the new structure [13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

If you're really determined to use php, then I'd suggest using background workers on a queue - this way each worker can process a small amount of records each (maybe 1000 - avoiding memory problems). This would take a while longer to run, and also to setup. We've used [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) for something similar (running data from a DB into redis) with good success.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your suggestion. I will try to implement. Is there any method where we can use exec() and we can set same page with offset and limit, so that the page will create a new batch and the old one close when it complete its task

Comment: @sanjeev - You could have the page process the batch and then redirect to itself passing in the limit & offset - but you would still potentially have the same memory / timeout issues (there is something similar to this in drupal, which may help you - [Drupal Batch API](https://www.drupal.org/node/180528)). If I were you, I'd at least create a script to run on the command line - avoiding the php timeouts.